# How to use pytest fixture with fixture factory?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pytest, fixtures

In scikit-learn, there is a function `parametrize_with_checks()` that is used as a pytest fixture factory--it returns a `pytest.mark.parametrize` fixture, and is called as a decorator with an iterable of estimators, e.g.

```py
@parameterize_with_checks(list_of_estimators)
```

My issue is that my list of estimators may change (or I may have multiple lists), and each list I am setting up in a fixture.

Here is a M(N)WE:

```py
import pytest
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.utils.estimator_checks import parametrize_with_checks


@pytest.fixture
def models():
    return (LinearRegression(fit_intercept=flag) for flag in (False, True))


class TestModels:
    @parametrize_with_checks(models)
    def test_1(self, estimator, check):
        check(estimator)
        print("Do other stuff...")

    def test_2(self, models):
        print("Do even more stuff...")
```

However, `models` is still a function object when it is passed to `parametrize_with_checks`, so it throws an error. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parametrize_with_checks()` can not work with the values set by fixtures. It handles `models` just as a function, not a fixture. You can access fixtures only from test functions.
So, looks like you need to set the `models` as a list or make a call to the model function in `parametrize_with_checks()`

```
import pytest
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.utils.estimator_checks import parametrize_with_checks


MODELS = [LinearRegression(fit_intercept=flag) for flag in (False, True)]


@pytest.fixture()
def models():
    return [LinearRegression(fit_intercept=flag) for flag in (False, True)]


class TestModels:
    @parametrize_with_checks(MODELS)
    # OR
    # @parametrize_with_checks(estimators=models())
    def test_1(self, estimator, check):
        check(estimator)
        print("Do other stuff...")

    def test_2(self, models):
        print("Do even more stuff...")
```

Comment: This is a simple option and one that I will probably go with, thank you. sklearn also has a `check_estimator` function which I might be able to use (with the `pytest-cases` package) to get the hierarchical testing I want; `parametrize_with_checks` is useful as it breaks all of the tests out.